# How to implement the Like button in different html pages

Tags: button, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have followed the doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ to implement the Like Button. basically, I have put one like button on e.g www.foobar.com/index.html

So when user A clicks the Like button, my page "Foobar rules" will appear on his "Likes and Interests" section. Clicking the link will redirect him to www.foobar.com. 
So far everything is Great!

When the same user A clicks on the Like button on e.g. www.foobar.com/guestbook.html, the page "guest book" will appear on his "Likes and Interests" section (links to www.foobar.com/guestbook.html).

Question is How do I implement the Like button on the guestbook.html so the user A clicks on Like button will only see one link "Foobar rules" in his "Likes and Interests" section which goes to www.foobar.com. each Like button has its own counts.

I am using XFBML version of Like plugin code, opengraph.

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to change parametr inside the code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.foobar.cz/### HERE COME THE PAGE ###" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's documentation states:

> Attributes: href - the URL to like. The XFBML version defaults to the current page.

You could try using the HTML5 or IFRAME-code instead of XFBML. I had the same problem, the IFRAME-code worked for me.

Comment: i just now tested with HTML5 and IFRAME code version, and I still see the same issue. Any more ideas where it possible can be wrong is appreciated.. Thanks